# Самый быстрый эмулятор Android для слабых ПК для работы с приложениями инстаграмм

Tags: android, windows, instagram, эмулятор, виртуальная-машина

Подскажите какой по вашему мнению самый Android для слабых ПК для работы с приложениями инстаграмм, вк,fb. Не для игр. Не требующий много ресурсов и быстро запускающиеся.

Answer (score 3):

Nox Player - один из самых быстрых эмуляторов андроид для пк.

Answer (score 1):

**GenyMotion** - Хороший эмулятор, частично платный

**BlueStack** - Бесплатный и часто используемый для тех функций которые вы описали

**NoxPlayer** - Бесплатный и похож на BlueStack, что быстрее я не могу сказать.

Сам использую **GenyMotion** и могу его рекомендовать, стабильный и мощный.

Answer (score 1):

**Genymotion**

Удобен тем, что есть много образов под разные АПИ. Не для игр. Нормально не поддерживает ARM.
Удобен для тестов приложений, при разработке. Однако нет x64.

**Memu**

Игровой эмулятор. Есть 4 и 5 андроид.

**Droid4x**

Основной рабочий эмулятор. Работает стабильно. Некоторые настройки слетают при перезапуске. Стартует довольно быстро. Нормально расходует память.

**BlueStacks 0.8**

Игровой эмулятор. Используется старая версия. 15 АПИ. Работает достаточно шустро.

Я бы рекомендовал использовать BlueStacks 0.8 или же что-то поновее, вроде Droid4x или Memu. У меня Nox в последнее время бывает крайне нестабилен.